# Expose Sitecore/Sitecore Commerce Items to third party by using custom API

Tags: data-exchange-framework, sitecore-services-client, data-provider

Below are the possible ways to expose sitecore data to third party:

1. Item Web API
2. Sitecore Client Services
3. Data exchange framework
4. Sitecore Data Providers

I've following challenges to implement these approaches:

**Item Web API** -> As per my knowledge we can't customize this so I am not using this.

**Sitecore Client Services** -> Can we customize this and expose through Asp.net Web API? If yes then any reference to kick start.

**Data exchange framework** -> I used to import data from xml but how to expose sitecore data to third party?

**Sitecore Data Providers** -> I've gone through [John West](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/when-to-implement-data-providers-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms) article but it seems Sitecore Data Providers is not suitable approach to expose data to third party. If you have different thoughts then please share.

Apart from this, is there any other approach that we can use?

Comment: You can add Sitecore Media Framework to the list.

Comment: You can use Sitecore Data Exchange Framework to expose data to third party components.  It depends on existed providers or develop your own. For example there is Dynamics CRM connector that allows to get data from CRM to xDB or from xDB to CRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore Client Services is the one you need to be looking at. There might be a way with DXF as well but I am not too familiar with it.

As for Sitecore Client Services:

> Sitecore.Services.Client provides a service layer on both the server and the client side of Sitecore applications that you use to develop data-driven applications.
>
> Sitecore.Services.Client is configurable and extendable, and the framework and scaffolding it provides help you create the client-server communication in an application in a consistent way. Sitecore.Services.Client uses the **ASP.NET Web API** as a foundation.

A few links:

- [Sitecore.Services.Client](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/sitecoreservicesclient)
- [Developer's Guide to Sitecore.Services.Client](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/developer%27s_guide_to_sitecore.services.client_sc75-a4.pdf)

On a final note; you can expose data through pretty much any means allowed by regular ASP.NET. So Web Services and so on. Sitecore Client Services just provides you with a framework to jumpstart things a bit.